# phpMyAdmin Multi Server Setup Issue - Server Choice Never Displayed

Tags: linux, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a phpMyAdmin installed in my Ubuntu-14.04 LTS server. I want to manage other MySQL databases in different servers (all Ubuntu) across my VPC. I have enabled access to the servers using the AWS security policy and opened the port 3306 over the network as well as the Internet.

Moreover, I have added the following entry for Multi-Server setup in phpMyAdmin configuration file `config-inc.php`:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose']       = 'Server-2';  
//$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host']          = 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx';  
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host']          = 'server2.xxxxx.com';  
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port']          = '3306';  
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type']  = 'tcp';  
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension']     = 'mysqli';    
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress']      = false;    
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type']     = 'cookie';  
$i++;
```

I have even double checked remote server connectivity of MySQL from Linux command shell and it works fine.

But even after adding the above-mentioned entries in the configuration file and restarting Apache web-server, the prompt for "Server Choice" never appears in the phpMyAdmin landing page. Can anyone please let me know if I am missing anything or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Please try loading the config file directly, such as `https://example.com/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php`. If you get a blank screen, that is good; an error message is of course a problem. Also, can you enhance your answer to include your entire `config.inc.php`, obscuring as you have here any sensitive information such as hostnames or passwords?

Comment: I asked a similar question but nobody was able to answer it... http://serverfault.com/questions/825291/use-phpmyadmin-with-multiple-databases-and-http-auth

Answer (score 1):

It appears file permissions are to blame. Please check your configuration files and ensure they are readable by the apache2 user 'www-data'

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24452677/phpmyadmin-neginx-error-log-check-group-www-data-has-read-access-and-open-bas

```
$ sudo chmod 755 /var/lib/phpmyadmin              
$ sudo chmod 664 /var/lib/phpmyadmin/blowfish_secret.inc.php 
$ sudo chmod 664 /var/lib/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php 
$ sudo chmod 664 /etc/phpmyadmin/config-db.php
```

For me, this may have happened when I replaced Ubuntu's default phpmyadmin with the latest from a PPA:
https://launchpad.net/~nijel/+archive/ubuntu/phpmyadmin